# MYSQL Trigger Select & Update in same trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

### OK, I'm trying to read a value from one table and update the value in another based on the value. In other words, I need a quantity from one table to be subtracted from the same part number in another. Perhaps there is a better way to do it but I'm trying to do it in a Trigger. ** When I run it as a query it works fine. However, as a trigger not so well. I would appreciate a little help.
Thanks

```
Create Trigger Quantity
After INSERT
    ON Trans for each ROW

BEGIN
select Product, Qty into @A1,@A2
From Trans
order by TransID desc
limit 1;

Select Parts.Part_ID Into @A3
From Parts
Where Parts.PartNo = @A1;

Update Parts
set Parts.Qty_OnHand = Parts.Qty_OnHand - @A2
Where Parts.Part_ID = @A3;

end;
```

---

It will not let me create the Trigger because of the syntax.

```
Trans
 `TransID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date_Time` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `Cap_Data` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Job_Number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Product` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Qty` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Cost` float NOT NULL

Parts
`Part_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Qty_OnHand` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Reorder_Point` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `PartNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Cost` float NOT NULL,
  `Note` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Vendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Manufacturer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Hyperlink` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Image_Path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UL_Doc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Stock_Item` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Barcode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UL_File_No` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Bin_Loc` varchar(8) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Ignoring any issues with logic you may have failed to set delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xUwxSKXjNFrv8y7wkESyZ/0 You could improve this question by telling us your mysql version and how/what UI you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the quantity is big enough for the reduction before you try to add a row or you have to extent the trigger to catch that and raise an error

> ```
> CREATE tABLE Trans
>  (`TransID` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `Date_Time` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
>   `Cap_Data` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>   `Job_Number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>   `User` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
>   `Product` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
>   `Qty` int(20) NOT NULL,
>   `Cost` float NOT NULL)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE 
> Parts
> (`Part_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `Qty_OnHand` int(6) NOT NULL,
>   `Reorder_Point` int(6) NOT NULL,
>   `PartNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `Description` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
>   `Cost` float NOT NULL,
>   `Note` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>   `Category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>   `Vendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `Manufacturer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   `Hyperlink` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>   `Image_Path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `UL_Doc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `Stock_Item` bit(1) NOT NULL,
>   `Barcode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `UL_File_No` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
>   `Bin_Loc` varchar(8) NOT NULL)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Parts VALUES(1,10,0,0,0,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,1,9,9,9)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> Create Trigger Quantity
> After INSERT
>     ON Trans for each ROW
> Update Parts
> set Qty_OnHand = Qty_OnHand - NEW.Qty 
> Where Part_ID = (Select Part_ID 
>           From (SELECT * FROM Parts) p
> Where PartNo = NEW.Product);
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Trans VALUES (1,now(),1,1,1,0,1,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Parts
> ```
>
> ```
> Part_ID | Qty_OnHand | Reorder_Point | PartNo | Description | Cost | Note | Category | Vendor | Manufacturer | Hyperlink | Image_Path | UL_Doc | Stock_Item | Barcode | UL_File_No | Bin_Loc
> ------: | ---------: | ------------: | :----- | :---------- | ---: | :--- | :------- | :----- | :----------- | :-------- | :--------- | :----- | :--------- | :------ | :--------- | :------
>       1 |          9 |             0 | 0      | 0           |    9 | 9    | 9        | 9      | 9            | 9         | 9          | 9      | 1          | 9       | 9          | 9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c0f4d242f0cebe2beae5130d521fe6b)*